# Kinetic Scroll in Maverick

Tags: 10.10

I have Sony VAIO FW 230J laptop. I was using Lucid and upgraded my system to Maverick beta in September 2010. Although there were few issues with beta release on my system although I did not felt myself in any deadlock. The most notable experience on my ubuntu was the smooth and kinetic scrolling and very sensitive touch pad experience with finer control that was oddly normal in previous releases and even on windows 7 currently. Definitely this release of ubuntu is improved for touch UI experience. I believe that this is magic of 10.10.

For my official system I waited until the final release was out. After installing (upgrading) official system to Maverick I am not feeling the same smooth and kinetic scroll experience.

My laptop has

```
 Graphics: Intel DMA-X4500MHD
```

while my official desktop has

```
 Graphics: Intel DMA-X4500HD
```

Do I need to install or update some software package to have similar kinetic scroll experience?

Comment: It is "Maverick", not "Mevrik" -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need some other sotware, the problem is you can't get kinetic scrolling on a desktop unless you use some kind of trackpad or something.